# When does a certain number is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, integers, square-numbers

I've the following number:

$$12\left(n-2\right)^2x^3+36\left(n-2\right)x^2-12\left(n-5\right)\left(n-2\right)x+9\left(n-4\right)^2\tag1$$

Now I know that $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $n\ge3$ (and $n$ has a given value) besides that $x\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $x\ge2$.

I want to check if the number is a perfect square.

Yesterday, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/7110582?noredirect=1) question was answered using the software [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/). And the code that was used is the following:

```
E = EllipticCurve([0, β, 0, γ, δ])
P = E.integral_points()
for p in P:
    if p[0] % α == 0:
        print(p[0] // α, p[1] // α)
```

Using $(1)$ I found that:

- $$\alpha=12(n-2)^2\tag2$$
- $$\beta=36(n-2)\tag3$$
- $$\gamma=-144(n-5)(n-2)^3\tag4$$
- $$\delta=1296(n-4)^2(n-2)^4\tag5$$

Now, when I tried $n=71$ it should have found that $x=1585$ is a solution but it gave me nothing in return.

> What mistake have I made?

Comment: Removing the **perfect-numbers** tag, as this question is not related.

Answer (score 0):

You must first multiply all coefficients by $144(n-2)^4$ in order to bring your equation to elliptic curve form ( the coefficient of $x^3$ and $y^2$ has to be $1$ in particular) this is why in the end you will also mod out and divide by $a$.

To clarify use instead the following in the code: $\beta'=\beta,\gamma'=12(n-2)^2\gamma,\delta'=144(n-2)^4\delta$ and $a'=12(n-2)^2=a$.

In general you have $y^2=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, multiplying by $a^2$ then gives $(ay)^2=(ax)^3+b(ax)^2+ac(ax)+a^2d$. So $b'=b,c'=ac,d'=a^2d$.

Comment: Okay, so where is my mistake? Are my coefficients wrong?

Comment: Yes apologies, I made a mistake in phrasing my reasoning, you multiply each coefficient by the above mentioned quantity

Comment: I found again no solutions!

Comment: E = EllipticCurve([0, 3085128, 0, -3877709723712, 163784411936219808])
P = E.integral_points()
for p in P:
    if p[0] % 414 == 0:
        print(p[0] // 414, p[1] // 414)

Comment: Ok it should work now, I forgot about $y^2$ before

Comment: Again no solutions! But if you are right the answer I got yesterday is also wrong because he get's the same coefficients I got using the formulas in my question?!

Comment: E = EllipticCurve([0, 2484, 0, -178374647290752, 430437227046045063250176])
P = E.integral_points()
for p in P:
    if p[0] % 57132 == 0:
        print(p[0] // 57132, p[1] // 57132)

Comment: I checked it also and you've made a mistake, but I not see where yet

Comment: I also checked $n=4$ and it gave the solution I need to find using my coefficients

Comment: I wasn’t really concerned with the actual numbers as you can tell (I wanted to showcase the method mostly), but I’ll leave it here as reference in case someone can fix it...